# iOS UINavigationBar tint color appears darker than color set

Tags: ios, colors, uinavigationbar

I am setting a custom appearance for a specific navigation controller:

```
//Set Cutom Nav Bar Appearance
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationControllerClass class], nil] setBackgroundImage: nil forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationControllerClass class], nil] setBarTintColor: self.tableView.backgroundColor];
```

When the navigation controller is displayed, the expected color is RGB(247, 247, 247) - which I have double checked is also the value of the tableView.background color when the value is set - but it appears on screen as RGB( 227, 227, 227). Could there be a different property of UINavigationBar's appearance proxy that is changing the color displayed on screen?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Additionally, if I set the barTintColor directly using the desired color, the barTintColor displayed on screen is still darker than expected:

```
UIColor* navBarBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed: (247.0 / 255.0) green: (247.0 / 255.0) blue: (247.0 / 255.0) alpha: 1];
//Set Cutom Nav Bar Appearance
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationControllerClass class], nil] setBackgroundImage: nil forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationControllerClass class], nil] setBarTintColor: navBarBackgroundColor];
```

**Solution**

Here is the solution code derived from @Matt's answer. Hope it helps someone out

```
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(context, [self.tableView.backgroundColor CGColor]);
CGContextFillRect(context, rect);
UIImage *navBarImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

//Set Cutom Nav Bar Appearance
[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[MyNavigationControllerClass class], nil] setBackgroundImage: navBarImage forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Comment: Would you please add the line of code where you are specifying the RGB values?

Comment: Could it be the alpha or transparency settings of the bar? Have you checked that?

Comment: @William the tableView.background color that is being forwarded to the navigationBar is being set in storyboard. Regardless though, even if I explicitly set the desired color, it is still being shown as darker than the set color (code in Edit above)

Comment: @Glavid The answer below was not helpful? As they are pointing out the translucency of the navigationbar, it could be just that. The background color of the tableview, plus the color of the translucent navbar may result in the darker color you see.

Comment: @William Question updated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The way to set the color of a navigation bar exactly is the precise opposite of what you're doing. You are giving it a tint color and no background image. Instead, give it a background image consisting of a rectangle of the desired color - and no tint color.

Also set its `translucent` to NO.

Comment: Seems odd to have to set the background color in this way, but it does work. I guess barTintColors get modified by the OS before being displayed on screen, so as you say this is the "best way to get an EXACT" color. Thanks for the help.. posting solution code back in the question.

Comment: It's partly the whole translucency business, and partly the meaning of the word "tint" (which needs to be taken seriously).