# Color from nib color picker is different then [UIColor -colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:]

Tags: ios

I've got a certain color that I'd like to use throughout my app. That color has got these RGBA values:

R:217
G:66
B:60
A:1.0

Now, in some nibs I'm using this color as a background color via the color picker.
In other cases, I'm using this code to set colors manually

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:217.f/255.f green:66.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f alpha:1.0f];
```

However, I am finding that the colors do not match visually!!

[image]

[image]
What is going on? Why do the colors look so different?

Printing out the colors gives me this:

```
(lldb) po [self.programticLabel backgroundColor]
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.85098 0.258824 0.235294 1

(lldb) po [self.nibLabel backgroundColor]
UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.805696 0.171843 0.181392 1
```

Comment: What is that doesn't match? Is it somewhere in that screen shot? If so, where are we supposed to look? What is it that's different from what in that screen shot? And what happens in the running app? (That's all that matters, after all.)

Comment: Note that your specifications don't match: `R:217 B:66 G:60 A:1.0` has a blue of 66, but `[UIColor colorWithRed:217.f/255.f green:66.f/255.f blue:60.f/255.f alpha:1.0f]` has a blue of 60.

Comment: sorry that was a typo - the code and the pic match up.

Comment: Your new screen shot looks like you've got a navigation bar. It's not the same because it has translucency. This has nothing to do with your color; it's how you are configuring the nav bar. You need to show your code. Even better, delete this question and start over with a better question - i.e., ask about how to set the color of a navigation bar.

Comment: Also take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090256/ios-uinavigationbar-tint-color-appears-darker-than-color-set

Comment: it is a navigationbar but transluscent is set to NO. I also verified that using a basic UIColor constructor like +redColor or +blueColor work as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aha! The answer can be found here:

[Weird colors in XCode Interface Builder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488378/weird-colors-in-xcode-interface-builder/9203647#9203647)

If you go to the RGB color picker in Xcode - be sure to take note of the settings button to the right of the dropdown. RGB is defined as a part of a color space -- and mine was not set to Apple's.

Comment: Oooh, good answer. - However, I still think you should delete your question. It's a duplicate and is just wasting bandwidth.

Comment: But this is not a duplicate, it's an entirely different issue. Your problem was not the navigation bar, but the color space setting.